# Rails Testing redirection in controller create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, redirect, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newbie in Rails trying to test the creation of a `batiment` and the redirection to the `show`page of this created `batiment`.

**batiments_controller_test.rb**

```
test "should create batiment" do
 post :create, batiment: {nom: "New batiment"}
 assert_response :success
 assert_redirected_to assigns(:batiment)
end
```

**batiments_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @batiment = Batiment.new(batiment_params)
 if @batiment.save
  flash[:notice] = "Bâtiment créé!"
  redirect_to @batiment
 else
  render('new')
 end
end
```

**routes**

```
                   POST   /batiments(.:format)                              batiments#create
   new_batiment GET    /batiments/new(.:format)                          batiments#new
  edit_batiment GET    /batiments/:id/edit(.:format)                     batiments#edit
       batiment GET    /batiments/:id(.:format)                          batiments#show
```

Terminal when running test:

```
     1) Error:
BatimentsControllerTest#test_should_create_batiment:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"batiments", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/batiments_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:BatimentsControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the batiment could not be created, so the action rendered the view `'new'`. That explains why `assert_response :success` passed (the request returned http code 200), and why `assert_redirected_to assigns(:batiment)` failed (the batiment is not saved, so it has no id).

Check why the save failed (maybe a validation failed ? check `@batiment.errors`), and rewrite the test like this:

```
test 'should create batiment' do
 assert_difference('Batiment.count') do
   post :create, batiment: {nom: 'New batiment'}
 end
 assert_redirected_to assigns(:batiment)
end
```

Comment: You're completely right , this was a validation failed. I feel stupid. Thank you so much